# How to write namespaced element attributes with LXML?

Tags: python, lxml, xml-namespaces, cytoscape

I'm using lxml (2.2.8) to create and write out some XML (specifically XGMML).  The [app](http://www.cytoscape.org/) which will be reading it is apparently fairly [fussy](http://wiki.cytoscape.org/XGMML) and wants to see a top level element with:

```
<graph label="Test" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xlink="h
ttp://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-
ns#" xmlns:cy="http://www.cytoscape.org" xmlns="http://www.cs.rpi.edu/XGMML"  di
rected="1">
```

How do I setup those `xmlns:` attributes with lxml ?  If I try the obvious

```
root.attrib['xmlns:dc']='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'
root.attrib['xmlns:xlink']='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
root.attrib['xmlns:rdf']='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'
root.attrib['xmlns:cy']='http://www.cytoscape.org'
root.attrib['xmlns']='http://www.cs.rpi.edu/XGMML'
```

lxml throws a `ValueError: Invalid attribute name u'xmlns:dc'`

I've used XML and lxml a fair amount in the past for simple stuff, but managed to avoid needing to know anything about namespaces so far.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unlike ElementTree or other serializers that would allow this, `lxml` needs you to set up these namespaces beforehand:

```
NSMAP = {"dc" : 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1',
         "xlink" : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'}

root = Element("graph", nsmap = NSMAP)
```

(and so on and so forth for the rest of the declarations)

And then you can use the namespaces using their proper declarations:

```
n = SubElement(root, "{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1}foo")
```

Of course this gets annoying to type, so it is generally beneficial to assign the paths to short constant names:

```
DCNS = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1"
```

And then use that variable in both the `NSMAP` and the `SubElement` declarations:

```
n = SubElement(root, "{%s}foo" % (DCNS))
```

Answer (score 6):

Using [ElementMaker](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html#the-e-factory):

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import lxml.builder as builder
E = builder.ElementMaker(namespace='http://www.cs.rpi.edu/XGMML',
                         nsmap={None: 'http://www.cs.rpi.edu/XGMML',
                         'dc': 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/',
                         'xlink': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',
                         'rdf': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#',
                         'cy': 'http://www.cytoscape.org', })
graph = E.graph(label="Test", directed="1")
print(ET.tostring(graph, pretty_print=True))
```

yields

```
<graph xmlns:cy="http://www.cytoscape.org" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.cs.rpi.edu/XGMML" directed="1" label="Test"/>
```