# Python lxml.etree: how to add 'xml:lang="en-US"' as a namespace

Tags: python-3.x, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to create a xml whose first element is:

```
<speak version="1.0"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US">
</speak>
```

I am able to add the first attributes with...

```
from lxml.etree import Element, SubElement, QName, tostring 
root = Element('speak', version="1.0",
               xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis")
```

...but not the namespace `xml:lang="en-US"`. Based on several tuto/question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7703144/3154274) and [this](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) I tried many solutions but none worked.

For example, I tried this :

```
class XMLNamespaces:
    xml = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis'

root.attrib[QName(XMLNamespaces.xml, 'lang')] = "en-US"
```

But the ouput is

```
<speak xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" ns0:lang="en-US">
```

How can I create the `xml:lang="en-US"` of my first xml element?

Comment: The URI for the `xml` prefix is `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17477289/407651

Comment: It's working, thanks so much! Please post it as an answer so I can upvote you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special `xml:` prefix is associated with the http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace URI.

The following code adds `xml:lang="en-US"` to the root element:

```
root.attrib[QName("http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", "lang")] = "en-US"
```